# How to provide artifacts to a maven project if those are not in public repository?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I cloned an open source library project from Github, that I'd like to use for my own Java project. This library depends on some other jars that cannot be found in any public repository. This causes `mvn package` to fail:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project commons-gdx-core: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project 
com.gemserk.commons.gdx:commons-gdx-core:jar:0.0.11-SNAPSHOT: 
The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
com.badlogic.gdx:gdx:jar:0.9.8-SNAPSHOT, 
com.gemserk.animation4j:animation4j-core:jar:0.2.2-SNAPSHOT,
com.gemserk.vecmath:vecmath:jar:1.5.3-GEMSERK: 
Could not find artifact com.badlogic.gdx:gdx:jar:0.9.8-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

I think I can get these jars from other sources but I don't know how to tell maven where to look for them.

Comment: If they're not available in any public maven repositories then you have to find them somewhere and install to your local maven repository. If you're planning to distribute your project you'll need to make them available to other people (for example, by uploading them somewhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as example, we have Oracle JDBC driver. You must install it into your local maven repository.

1. Download your lib to local folder (i.e.: Path/to/private/library.jar)
2. mvn install:install-file -Dfile= -DgroupId=
   -DartifactId= -Dversion= -Dpackaging=jar

Or, a more advanced way, if you have a Maven Repository (like Sonatype Nexus), you can deploy it on repository and map it on your project. But, I think that you need the first option.

Answer (score 2):

Use the repositories and repository tags to point to the private repositories in your pom file or update your settings.xml in the same way.  Maven will download the artifacts once you tell it where to look.

Comment: And if the jar are not presented in any repository, I have to install them using this? http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Answer (score 1):

Answers from apast and Chris are both correct. But if you change your computer or clean up your local repository, you project still can't be compiled. What I suggest is using system dependencies and add the jar under git version control. [Here's](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies) an example.